# What is this syntax in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax, cookies

I'm working on modifying a script to better suit my needs, and I came across this line in the code:

```
return isset($_COOKIE[$parameter_name]) ? $_COOKIE[$parameter_name] : "";
```

I know that the function itself is essentially a cookie getter method, but I'm not quite sure what that syntax (i.e. the "?" and ":") means. I apologize if this is a really dumb question, but could someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 13):

It's a [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) and is basically a more compact way of writing an if/then/else.

So in your code sample it's being used instead of having to write:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[$parameter_name])) {
    return $_COOKIE[$parameter_name];
} else {
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's a [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) which is not PHP specific and exists in most langauges.

```
(condition) ? true_case : false_case
```

And in my opinion should only be used as short one liners like in your example. Otherwise readabilty would suffer – so never nest ternary operation (though it's possible to do so).

Answer (score 2):

The ? : are the ternary operator.  Its a very quick if a then b else c:

```
if (a) { return b; } else { return c; }
```

is equivalent to:

```
return a ? b : c;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 return isset($_COOKIE[$parameter_name]) ? $_COOKIE[$parameter_name] : "";
```

The function return:

```
$_COOKIE[$parameter_name]
```

If $_COOKIe with specified parameter_name exists, empty string otherwise.

**Prototype**:

```
condition ? this runs if condition true : this runs if condition false;
```