# What is the meaning of the '?', '()', and ':' symbols in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, definition

I've finally remembered what to ask. I never really got what : and ? do when a variable is being defined like this:

```
$ip = ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

As you can see there is ? and : and ( )

Could anyone give me a brief detail about why and how they are used for?

Comment: Dupe [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080247/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-what-does-it-do), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030734/what-does-this-php-function-construct-do-and-where-can-i-find-more-documentat), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889373/quick-php-syntax-question), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913118/what-is-this-syntax-in-php), [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276909/php-syntax-question-what-does-the-question-mark-and-colon-mean-closed), etc.

Comment: I've tried searching >.>

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The expression looks like this:

```
$var = (condition) ? if_true : if_false
```

`?:` is the **[ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)**. If `condition` is true, `$var` will be assigned the value `if_true`; otherwise it will be assigned the value `if_false`.

In your particular case:

- This assigns the value of the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header to `$ip` if it exists; otherwise it uses the remote address itself.
- This is usually used as a way to get a client's IP address. However, note that in general this is a terrible way to check for client identity. See **[this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527638/getting-the-client-ip-address-remote-addr-http-x-forwarded-for-what-else-could)**. (Use session cookies or some sort of authentication if you need to make sure users don't clobber each other.)
- Also, it's `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, not `HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR`.
- Finally, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` can be a comma-delimited list of IP addresses, not just a single one, so this has the potential to be a bug.

Comment: Very brief. Accepted answer, also nice tips :)

Comment: Also would you mind doing a brief about multiple ternary operators within one logical statement. This will be helpful to others. +1

Comment: @RobertPitt: the brief advice would be: don't do it! Nested ternary operators quickly become unwieldy, unintelligible, unmaintainable code.

Comment: +1, and I cannot help but mention that X-Forwarded-For,like other headers, is completely spoofable. You could set `$ip` to `127.0.0.1` simply by saying so in your header. So this code would be open to "normal" bugs and "security" vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

It's known as a ternary operator and is shorthand for (in your case):

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR'])
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR'];
}
else
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"?:" (or ternary) operator
```

The expression (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3)  evaluates to expr2 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to FALSE

See this example:

```
<?php
// Example usage for: Ternary Operator
$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];

// The above is identical to this if/else statement
if (empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = 'default';
} else {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ternary form is basically a shortcut for if->then->else

I generally avoid it because it's not all that readable.

```
$ip = ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

is logically equivalent to:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR']){
   $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR'];
}else{
   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

It should be said that this is EXACTLY what this is most commonly used for: variable initialization. Very common with form data.